# Fortran operator assignment(=) for complex number matrix class

Tags: fortran, assignment-operator

How write assignment operator for complex number matrix class.
I know complex is standard in fortran.
For zcomplex_type works correct. I can assign real part of complex
number to real type, but in zmatrix_type doesn't work.
I must create matrix of real number in subroutine zmatrix_realmatrix_assign.

Error

```
mat1=tab
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 2 in assignment at (1)
```

````
module zmatrix_module
implicit none
type, public :: zcomplex_type

    real :: realis
    real :: imaginalis

end type zcomplex_type

type, public :: zmatrix_type
    type(zcomplex_type), dimension(:,:), allocatable, public :: zmatrix_data
end type zmatrix_type

    public :: zmatrix_allocate
    public :: zmatrix_free
    public :: zmatrix_set
    public :: zmatrix_print
    public :: assignment(=)
    
interface assignment(=)
procedure zcomplex_re_assign
procedure re_zcomplex_assign
procedure zmatrix_realmatrix_assign
end interface 
    
contains

subroutine zcomplex_re_assign(zcomplex1,real2)
type(zcomplex_type), intent(out) :: zcomplex1
real, intent(in) :: real2
        zcomplex1%realis =real2
        zcomplex1%imaginalis =0.0
end subroutine zcomplex_re_assign

subroutine re_zcomplex_assign(real2,zcomplex1)
real, intent(out) :: real2
type(zcomplex_type), intent(in) :: zcomplex1
        real2=zcomplex1%realis 
end subroutine re_zcomplex_assign

subroutine zmatrix_realmatrix_assign(zmatrix1,realmatrix2)
type(zmatrix_type), intent(out) :: zmatrix1
real,  intent(in) :: realmatrix2

    zmatrix1%zmatrix_data%realis=realmatrix2
    zmatrix1%zmatrix_data%imaginalis=0
end subroutine zmatrix_realmatrix_assign

subroutine zmatrix_allocate(zarray,rows)
    type(zmatrix_type), intent(out) :: zarray
    integer, intent(in) :: rows
    allocate(zarray%zmatrix_data(1:rows, 1:rows))
end subroutine zmatrix_allocate

subroutine zmatrix_free(zarray)
    type(zmatrix_type), intent(inout) :: zarray
    deallocate(zarray%zmatrix_data)
end subroutine zmatrix_free

subroutine zmatrix_set(zarray, rows, re_values, im_values)
    type(zmatrix_type), intent(inout) :: zarray
    integer, intent(in) :: rows
    real, intent(in) :: re_values, im_values
    integer :: i,j
    do i=1, rows
        do j=1, rows
            zarray%zmatrix_data(i,j)%realis = re_values
            zarray%zmatrix_data(i,j)%imaginalis = im_values
        enddo
    enddo
end subroutine zmatrix_set

subroutine zmatrix_print(array,rows)
    type(zmatrix_type), intent(in) :: array
    integer, intent(in) :: rows
    integer i,j
    
    do i=1, rows
        write(*,*) (array%zmatrix_data(i,j), j=1, rows)
    enddo
    write(*,*)
end subroutine zmatrix_print

end module zmatrix_module

Program main
use zmatrix_module
implicit none
type(zmatrix_type) :: mat1
real :: tab(3,3)
call zmatrix_allocate(mat1,3)
tab=3
mat1=tab
print *, mat1

call zmatrix_free(mat1)

End Program main ```
````

Comment: As the error says, you have an array on one side (`tab` on the right) and a scalar (`mat1`) on the other side of the assignment. This isn't allowed. What do you think should happen?

Comment: To take @francescalus  comment further your overloaded assignment only describes the case of assigning a scalar to the matrix, not a 2D array

Comment: When you assign a 3×3 matrix to a `zcomplex_type` what did you intend to do?

Answer (score 1):

You created an overloaded assignment operator `zmatrix_realmatrix_assign` which takes a *scalar* `real` value as input and outputs a `zmatrix_type`.

My guess is that you probably want `zmatrix_realmatrix_assign` to do the following:

1. make it accept a *2d real array*: `real, intent(in) :: realmatrix2(:,:)`
2. allocate `zmatrix1%zmatrix_data` accordingly
3. set real/imag parts as previously done

```
  subroutine zmatrix_realmatrix_assign(this, rmat)
    type(zmatrix_type), intent(out) :: this
    real,               intent(in)  :: rmat(:,:)

    allocate (this%zmatrix_data(size(rmat, dim=1), size(rmat, dim=2)))
    this%zmatrix_data%realis     = rmat
    this%zmatrix_data%imaginalis = 0
  end subroutine
```

The assignment procedure explicitly allocates the data structure `this%zmatrix_data` such that the allocate call in your program is unnecessary

```
call zmatrix_allocate(mat1,3)
```

---

You could still use the `zmatrix_allocate` procedure by changing the intent in the assignment procedure but it is error prone (which is why I have added the tests for allocation)

```
  subroutine zmatrix_realmatrix_assign(this, rmat)
    type(zmatrix_type), intent(inout) :: this
    real,               intent(in)    :: rmat(:,:)

    if (.not. allocated(this%zmatrix_data)         ) error stop 'did not call allocate beforehand'
    if (any(shape(this%zmatrix_data) /= shape(rmat)) error stop 'wrong allocation of zmatrix_data'
    this%zmatrix_data%realis     = rmat
    this%zmatrix_data%imaginalis = 0
  end subroutine
```

Comment: can just declare it as an `elemental` function?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I was thinking about the same thing but did not see a possibility. The argument `type(zmatrix_type)` is scalar whereas `rmat` is a 2d array... You could post an answer if you find out how to do it.

Comment: Elemental would be difficult: the containing type is scalar and the array RHS wants to be assigned to the component of that scalar.